# mouse over on a map effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

How can i get the exact same mouse over  effect like [this](http://www.politico.com/2012-election/map/#/President/2012/) map.It's  got data from every states with the % of each candidate ,their name ,the name of the corresponding state etc.. And how do you make the box follow the mouse like it is on the app.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn what kinds of questions should (and shouldn't) be asked here. As it is, your question is too broad, too vague, and too lacking in your own code for us to address it.

Comment: Just use google map API, it has all you need: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin allows you to do exactly that.

- http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/
- http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html